# php passing multiple variable

Tags: php, variables, href

```
<?php
//link maklumat terperinci daerah

$daerah_ejen=str_replace(" ", "+", $daerah_ejen);
$detail_name_link = '<a onmouseover="Tip(\'Klik untuk lihat maklumat terperinci\')" onmouseout="UnTip()" href=laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen='.$daerah_ejen.'&kumpulan_ejen ='.$kumpulan_ejen.'>'.number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',').'</a>';
?>
```

WHY my passing variable for $kumpulan_ejen not appear in url.. I got `/laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen=SABAK+BERNAM&kumpulan_ejen`             *variable for kumpulan_ejen no passing to other page.

Comment: how to you show your passing value in next page?

Comment: make sure it is not already empty `$kumpulan_ejen`

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this code

```
$detail_name_link = '<a onmouseover="Tip(\'Klik untuk lihat maklumat terperinci\')" onmouseout="UnTip()" href="laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen='.$daerah_ejen.'&kumpulan_ejen ='.$kumpulan_ejen.'">'.number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',').'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`href=laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen=`

put `"` after the `href=` like this `href="YOURURLHERE"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put "" for href attribute.

```
href="laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen='.$daerah_ejen.'&kumpulan_ejen ='.$kumpulan_ejen.'" >'.number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',').'</a>';
```